# Which is the best way to produce electricity?

Tags: electromagnetic

To generate electricity from a DC type motor generator which of the following is the best way?

1) rotating coil wire in fixed magnetic field

2) rotating magnets in fixed coils setup

Which produce more electricity. This is for a simple science project.

Considering same rpm in both cases and same type of coils and same strength of magnets used.

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, by "best way" I assume you mean the most efficient way for the same input power of the DC motor.

The physical law for generation of electricity, here, is Faraday's Law. Faraday's Law states that electromotive force generated on a conductor is proportional to the rate of change of magnetic field on the conductor. According to this law, there is no difference between moving the coil or moving the magnet; they have the same effect.

Your question is more about the practices, i.e. setting up the actual circuitry. Your both proposals of current generation will result in an alternating current. In the first method you proposed you can use commutator to switch this alternating current to direct current. But in the second method you proposed, you cannot use the commutator, therefore you will have alternating current. Actually, you may come up with a commutator design but it should be more complicated than that are used for rotating coil arrangements.

In the end of the day, both methods will result in same efficiency-assuming every other effects are the same. Your decision should be on whether you want alternating current or direct current.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your requirement directly "Which produce more electricity" will be same amount of electricity. But considering your additional information " This is for a simple science project" I would advice you to go for second option "rotating magnets in fixed coils setup"

Amusing you want to use your electricity produce by your science project not inside 'rotating coils' but out of it. To get electricity out of rotating coil, you need some kind of 'connector' which will be more tricky if coils itself keep rotating. Make some coils with most conductive materials, connect it with your circuit and place your rotating magnet inside coils to generate current of electrons.

Consider my answer is most basic one to focus on your requirement.